# creating a literal for a Point - C++

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I am trying to do a simple library where the object is a point on the xy-axis.

I want to be able to use literals like this:

`Point a = (3,4);`

where `(3,4)` is a point literal.

I read about user defined literals, but (as I understood) this seems to be impossible.

May be `"(3,4)"_P` is possible as I understand it.

However, I found on [*this page*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) interesting use of user defined literals as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::complex<double> c = 1.0 + 1i;
    std::cout << "abs" << c << " = " << abs(c) << '\n';
}
```

I can under stand the part `1i` as a user defined literal, but not the whole thing `1.0 + 1i`.

What I am missing, and what is the nearest possible way of getting a literal similar to `(x,y)` without using `"`.

Comment: `1.0` is a `double`, `1i` is a `std::complex<double>`, and there's an `operator+` defined which takes those and results in `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: What do you mean by Point? Is it a class? If yes, give its code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434424/2805305) shows, the best way is to use uniform initialization.

However, **just for the fun of it**, you can (sort of) do this with User Defined Literals. My idea is to to have 2 literals for each coordinate and overload `operator+` between them to create the point.

Remember, this is just for fun, don't use this in a real code:

```
struct Px { int x; };
struct Py { int y; };

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

constexpr auto operator""_px(unsigned long long x) -> Px { return Px{(int)x}; }
constexpr auto operator""_py(unsigned long long y) -> Py { return Py{(int)y}; }

constexpr auto operator+(Px x, Py y) -> Point { return Point{x.x, y.y}; }
```

then you can have:

```
auto p = 3_px + 4_py; // p is deduced to type `Point`
```

Of course this is just a rough framework. Read [this great article](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/user-defined-literals-part-i/) to learn more about UDLs. You would need to deal with the narrowing conversion in a better way and propper use namespaces to make it a better solution.

As a bonus, you could also use `operator,` to create a syntax more appropriate to what you had in mind. But, don't do this, as overloading `operator,` is just evil:

```
auto operator,(Px x, Py y) -> Point { return Point{x.x, y.y}; }
```

```
auto p = (2_px, 1_py); // p is deduced to type `Point`
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* make up literals on your own, only create *suffixes* for literals. Like the shown `1i` or the standard language `f` as in `1.0f`. (See e.g. [this user-defined literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for more information.)

What you *can* to is to use [*uniform initialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) doing something like

```
Point a = { 3, 4 };  // note the use of curly-braces
```

Depending on what `Point` is you might need to add a suitable constructor to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

```
Point p = { 1,2 };
Point p2{ 1,2 };
Point p3(1,2);
```